# Why does EC2 have a seemingly random bare IP address for retrieving user and instance metadata?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm puzzled my EC2's use of the bare IP address `169.254.169.254` for the URI's to retrieve user and instance metadata. Wouldn't it be a better design decision for both Amazon and users if a hostname that was easier to remember was used, say `metadata.ec2.amazonaws.com`? If Amazon decides to change the bare IP address in the future, all the associated scripts that fetch user or instance metadata stop working.

You might say that I should use the Amazon supplied tool [EC2 Metadata](http://aws.amazon.com/code/1825), but it hasn't been updated in close to two years. Besides, the script itself would need to be updated should Amazon decide to change the IP address from the random `169.254.169.254` to something equally random, say `170.11.19.142`.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about AWS architecture which is out of scope on SO.

Comment: A host name would require working DNS (not guaranteed in some vpc environments). That ip is in the link local block so not completely random.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer where should I post questions about AWS architecture in that case?

Comment: @gkb0986, AWS Forum is the right place: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/index.jspa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something I'm missing here?

Yes - the `169.254.0.0/16` block is specified as a private block - see [169.254.0.0/16 addresses explained](http://packetlife.net/blog/2008/sep/24/169-254-0-0-addresses-explained/). Therefore, it's accessibly on that IP from machine *within* the private network - like your instance. Amazon isn't going to change this address to a whole other block, like your `170.11.19.142`, because it wouldn't be a private internal block.

The last two numbers, `169.254` are likely random, as you say. They were chosen by Amazon at some point in time, and will likely stay that way for quite a long time, seeing as Amazon has full control over that IP space.

> You might say that I should use the Amazon supplied tool EC2 Metadata

You should.

> , but it hasn't been updated in close to two years. Besides, the script itself would need to be updated should Amazon decide to change the IP address

Not necessarily. I haven't seen the script source code, but it's likely that, if the address is expected to change *any* time soon, it would check somehow with a root EC2 controller what IP the metadata server is at.